# Want To Display limited Number in Select Box

Tags: html, css, select

I have a **Select Box** which contains **200** records i want to display only **10**  at a time , looking to fix this with **CSS**.

Comment: `<select size="10"></select>`

Comment: Maybe first show us what you've done so far. We are here to help each other, not to write the code for someone.

Comment: You both are correct what i   have done is that i have added size="10" but its look and feel are no more like drop down its . now it shows up like this http://jsfiddle.net/f19xuqp6/ but i want it like http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7VCng/

Answer (score 0):

This will show you only 10 at a time regardless of how long the option list is.

```
 <select size="10">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   ...
   <option>20</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You both are correct what i have done is that i have added size="10" but its look and feel are no more like drop down its . now it shows up like this jsfiddle.net/f19xuqp6 but i want it like jsfiddle.net/danield770/7VCng

Comment: @BasharatAli so is the idea to only show 10 options in total out of your 200, because the second fiddle only shows 10 and what we gave you would do that also but allow you to scroll through the rest of the choices.

Comment: Yes You are right But I have Issue With Display ,How Its Displaying records after setting size to 10.

Comment: whats happening to it when you set the size to 10? Neither of the fiddles in your first comment were using the size=10 on the select.

Comment: when i set size =10 it shows like first fiddle but what i want is the display of second fiddle

Comment: Look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/m57qpt3y/ it displays just like the second fiddle you initially sent but allows you to scroll to the choices after the first 10. If you want to show ONLY 10 with no scroll then that is a different question than you asked at first.